# Custom prediction method in Keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I would like to use a custom prediction method in a given Kears model.

For example, say I have a binary classifier and my prediction rule says that if the probability that an example belongs to class A is less than 0.8 then it should be labeled as Class B (instead of 0.5 currently).

Is there any way to override `predict` method in Keras and not use `predict_proba` externally method and then applying the custom prediction rule?

Comment: You don't need to override it, you can just create a class that contains the model inside and its own predict method with your logic

Comment: This solution won't work if I want to optimize according to the custom prediction rule (e.g. use it in GridSearchCV to optimize hyper parameters)